# how to render text when value change flutter?

Tags: html, flutter, dart, text, render

I have code simple below

```
SingleChildScrollView(
   child: RichText(
      overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
      text: TextSpan(
        text: '${model.logMain.text}',
        style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
        children: <TextSpan>[
          TextSpan(
              text: '${model.value.text}',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ],
      ),
    ),
),
```

how to add (more) text when variable model.value.text change, please help me

Comment: put it on setState() as variable then it will update

Comment: I want like
out:   texta.....
when value change
out:   texta......
         textb......

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rebuild widget in Flutter when a change occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51033222/how-to-rebuild-widget-in-flutter-when-a-change-occurs)

Comment: I want render (add) text when value change

Comment: Statefull widget, read more about State Management, you can use GetX it will be easiest way to do it

Comment: you can show me, please

Answer (score 0):

when you change the value of data and you want the UI to Know about it just call

```
          setState(() {
                   value= "some new value";
                 });
```